# Physics Help Finding Voltage In the Secondary

Tags: iphone

A transformer has a primary voltage of 7,925.05 V and a primary current of 5.38 A, the number of loops in the primary is 8,080. The number of loops in the secondary is 2,667. What is the voltage in the secondary?

Comment: This doesn't seem related to programming, and certainly not related to iPhone. I believe you want to ask this on https://electronics.stackexchange.com. That said, you'll need to give some background on what part of this you're having trouble with. StackExchange sites generally are not used as calculators. For most sites, there is an expectation that your question would be searchable by others and help them when they have a similar question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.